# jQuery UI tabs help needed please

Tags: jquery-ui

I simply don't understand why I'm unable to make jQuery UI tabs work on my site.

http://swipe.visualise.ca/tabs.html

I want to use the image thumbnails as tabs.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Rather than making everyone click-through and hunt around, please quote the relevant code and markup *in* the question. This will increase your odds of getting a useful answer, and make the question and answer useful to people in the future when the linked resource has changed or been removed (link rot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so it needs CSS in order to work